# Does GEB supports selenium 3.0 version?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, spock, geb

Does GEB supports selenium 3? What is the most updated selenium version that geb supports? As per geb document, it is Selenium 2.52. Is that still correct..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is compatible with Selenium 3 as aparently Selenium 3 is backwards compatible with Selenium 2.

I would have switched Geb's build to 3 by now but some of the tests are using FF as the driver and I'd need to switch it over to Chrome given that Marionette, the new FF driver, is not finished yet and you have to use it with 3 as far as I understand.